# PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file"

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers

just trying to make a simple trigger in oracle SQL to log data when a row in a table is inserted updated or deleted. but am coming up with an error.

here is my code

```
create or replace trigger "APP_LOG_INSERT"
BEFORE
insert on "APPLICATIONS"
for each row
begin
INSERT INTO APP_LOG (APPLICATION_ID, SRN, APPLICATION_STATUS)
SELECT APPLICATION_ID, SRN, STATUS_ID
FROM INSERTED
end;
```

and the error i am getting is

```
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following: (
begin case declare end exception exit for goto if loop mod null pragma raise return select
update while with <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> <a bind variable>
<< continue close current delete fetch lock insert open rollback savepoint set sql execute
 commit forall merge pipe purge`
```

any help would be much appreciated, i am quite new to oracle so i may have just overlooked something simple

Comment: Oracle has something called `INSERTED` ???

Comment: it should be a virtual table created by oracle? got it from here https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/sqlserver/en-US/d246ecea-8d80-47f4-a955-472eae9ac36b/trigger-get-values-from-updated

Comment: It is a virtual table created by Microsoft SQL Server.  Oracle uses a different method for triggers.

Comment: ah, yeah, that makes sense. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably, you want something like this:

```
create or replace trigger "APP_LOG_INSERT"
BEFORE insert on "APPLICATIONS"
for each row
begin
    INSERT INTO APP_LOG(APPLICATION_ID, SRN, APPLICATION_STATUS)
        SELECT :new.APPLICATION_ID, :new.SRN, :new.STATUS_ID
        FROM dual;
end;
```

Comment: Or just `values( :new.application_id, :new.srn, :new.status_id)`.  No reason to do a `select from dual` for a single row.

Comment: @JustinCave . . . Do you know if there is a performance difference?  (Even so, it would be minor.)  I have a preference for `insert . . . select`, so I'm just wondering.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - I wouldn't expect there to be a meaningful difference.  Maybe an ever-so-slight hit if you're using an older version of Oracle that actually had to go do a logical read on `dual` rather than optimizing that away.